# Append table tr with modal pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I want to list some datas using table and tr td.....
when user click tr or td I want to show subject detail in modal pop up
altough alert work pop up not show-fire

If I use ul li instead of table tr td pop up show

so with this

```
$("#myUL").last().click(function() {
```

pop up show but 
with this

```
$(".table1").click(function() {
```

pop up not show
why?

```
$.each(data, function (i,item) {
    $("#infoList").append("<tr class='table1'><td>
     <span >"+ item.updated_at +"</span></td><td class='cell'><label >"+ item.baslik+"</label></br></td></tr>");
    $(".table1").click(function() {
        alert(item.baslik);
        $(".modal-body p").text(item.mesaj);
        $(".modal-header h4").text(item.baslik);
    });
});
```

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: is your alert showing? or click event is not firing at all? you can give a try by adding click event to td `$(".table1 td").click(function(){})`

Comment: @messerbill no error,alert work

Comment: @ArunKumar alert work...click even firing but pop up no work...I change this but still same error :   $(".table1 td").click(function() {

Comment: where is your code to open a modal popup? Can you post all required code?

Comment: @ArunKumar yes I added  modal pop up html...here is my html page:  http://hybridsoftware.net/ha/odemelerim.htm   you can click red table cell td

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing code to open the modal dialog in your click event also make sure you include bootstrap js file to use this code

```
$.each(data, function (i,item) {
    $("#infoList").append("<tr class='table1'><td>
     <span >"+ item.updated_at +"</span></td><td class='cell'><label >"+ item.baslik+"</label></br></td></tr>");
    $(".table1").click(function() {
        alert(item.baslik);
        $(".modal-body p").text(item.mesaj);
        $(".modal-header h4").text(item.baslik);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: hi,thank you it works,but it always  show last tr item(item.baslik)...If I click first one it still show last one content...Should I add last click event to click event?

Comment: I add this it look good  $(".table1 td").last().click(function() {